# How to deal with spam traffic?

Tags: google-analytics, spam-prevention, ddos

I started to notice some very odd behavior in my Google Analytics account on 23th October. I was averaging 700-800 sessions a day up to that point but on that day I had over 5.000 sessions. I first believe that something might have gone viral, but that wasn't the case, all this traffic was direct (!!!) so I checked Geo>Location and besides my usual locations one thing stood up:

City: Reston (Virginia)
Sessions: 4,292
New Sessions: 100% (!!!)
Bounce Rate: 100% (!!!)

The next day the traffic dropped, but was still above my average and every day after that the traffic kept on raising with the same behavior as above however there wasn't as much traffic from one city, now I had multiple cities each day. The odd thing is that all this spam traffic comes from cities on the east coast while my business is based on the west coast, my usual traffic wasn't contaminated at all.

My question to you is... what does this look like to an experienced eye and more importantly how do I stop it? Considering I'm not experienced (like, at all) with security issues, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Does this actually reflect in you server's access logs? If it doesn't, there is nothing you can do as spammers request GA script directly (without even visiting your site). Our you can set new counter (and lose all previous statistics) until they find its ID again.

Comment: That I did not check, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with spam hits is a pain. The only way out is to identify a 'signature' of the spam and filter or segment it out.

1. Hits to your site can be a number of types. Start by identifying which type you have. Check the following metrics: pageviews, screenviews, events, transactions, items, socials, exceptions, timings. You will have to switch through the various reports in GA to determine what type you are getting. Usually it is pageviews, but events are also popular.
2. Then drill into that hit type and try to determine a unique combination of dimensions that align with the spam traffic and not with your real traffic. There are over 400 dimensions and metrics in Google Analytics, so explore...hostname, page title, event category, keyword, source/medium, browser, city, flash version, service provider, campaign name, full referrer, screen resolution, user language, landing page, social action,
3. Build a segment to isolate the spam from your real data. Segments can be easily created, immediately tested, and have no effect on your underlying data. A lot of spammers fake traffic to sites without setting the correct Hostname value, so creating an include condition with valid hostnames gets rid of that junk. Your spam may differ.
4. Once you have confirmed that the segment gets rid of ONLY the spam traffic, try to create a view filter that reproduces the same conditions. Implement in a TEST view for a few days first to see it it works as expected. Segments conditions work differently than filters, so you need to TEST, TEST, TEST.  When you implement a filter, it changes the data and there is no way to undo it. ALWAYS keep an unfiltered view just in case.

One technique used by some people is to push a value into a custom dimension on every page in your site, then filtering all traffic to eliminate anything missing that custom value. Mixed results - not all spam will be affected and some valid traffic could actually get lost (test, test, test).

Good luck.

Comment: Late reply I know, but thanks for all the great pointers. After hours of data mining, I managed to identify the behavior I wanted to exclude and now our filtered view looks very clean.